# asp .net background image flickering on postback

Tags: css, asp.net, image, background-image, flicker

My background image is reloading on every postback. So it causes a flickering everytime you press a button. It occurs in Internet Explorer (Version 11.0.9600.17843 tested) and Chrome (Version 45.0.2454.93 m tested). In Firefox (Version 34.0.5 tested) it works. I have tested no other browsers so far. This is the code for the background image so far:

```
<style type="text/css">
body 
{
   background-image:  url(/Img/Besuchermanagement_1920_1080.jpg);

    background-attachment: inherit;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    background-position: center;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    min-height: 925px;

    opacity: 0.9
}       
</style>
```

I also added those meta tags when I read about an IE flickering bug:

```
<meta http-equiv="Page-Enter" content="blendTrans(Duration=0.2)" />
<meta http-equiv="Page-Exit" content="blendTrans(Duration=0.2)" />
```

But that didn't work for me.

So I added an image and set it invisible through this css

```
.backgroundImageFix 
{
    width: 1%;
    height: 1%;
    opacity: 0.0
}

<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" EnableTheming="True" ImageAlign="Bottom"  CssClass="backgroundImageFix"
    ImageUrl="~/Img/Besuchermanagement_1920_1080.jpg" />
```

And now I don't have any flickering issues any more.

But I don't understand why adding an image prevents the background image to reload on a postback. I hope anyone can explain it to me and maybe give me a better solution.

Comment: Are you using ajax postbacks, or is it a full page postback ?  Also is this webforms or mvc ?

Comment: This is webforms. There are checkboxes with AutoPostBack properties true and buttons with onclick methods on the code behind.

Comment: I presume you are not using an update panel.

Comment: But when I want to update a sql table I need that postback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

during post back the page reloads because it has a life cycle this makes the page to reload which is the flickering 
but to avoid that you can use update panel control in asp.net

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />

 <asp:UpdatePanel id="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
     <ContentTemplate>

              //your code here

      </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

this should stop you background image to flicker

Comment: Updatepanel does only update on client side? Because I need to update an sql table so the client has to communicate with the server through a postback?

Comment: yes update panel will work at client side but rest will be taken care by asp.net events all you have to do is try to write all of your buttons and content in update-panel  to stop the flickering issue

Comment: To put all my content in one update-panel helped for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options

You should use an update panel - it will only "postback" the required data inside the panel and redraw part of the screen inside the update pannel - take a read of [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398874.aspx) to see how microsoft ajax can help you. I think you should be using the update panel anyway as it is a better user experience.

Alternatively the issue can also be caused because the background colour  of the body is not set. it will then default ot transparent, and the page will be white. you can try setting the background colour to a colour similar to what the image has. I have seen this reduce the flicker on pages in the past.